# What is the contribution of leptonic CP violation (from neutrino mixing matrix) to baryon asymmetry of the universe?

Tags: particle-physics, cosmology

It is known that baryonic asymmetry in the universe (BAU) is of order $n_B/n_\gamma \equiv\eta \sim 10^{-10}$, but CP violation from CKM matrix is of order $10^{-20}$. Now that we know neutrinos mix, there may be CP violation from lepton sector too. How large is the contribution to $\eta$ from neutrino mixing matrix CP violation?

Comment: We're still at the stage where most theorists won't commit to a guess about $\delta_\text{CP}$. To the point that Murray Goodman thought that [arXiv:1709.10252](https://arxiv.org/abs/1709.10252) was worth mentioning in his [long-baseline neutrino newsletter for September 2017](http://www.hep.anl.gov/ndk/longbnews/1709.html).

Comment: @dmckee My recollection is that the old models from the 80's for baryon number generation involving right-handed neutrinos relies on lepton-number violation in the decay of the (lightest?) right-handed neutrino  at an earlier epoch, and then in the generation of the baryon number asymmetry from that lepton number asymmetry. But then the lepton number production is proportional to the CP-violating matrix of the mass matrix and to the ratio between the mass of the first and the second neutrino hierarchy iirc.

Comment: But, then from the top of my head, and I should really check, the constraints for the mechanism to work was that the lightest left-handed neutrino mass is smaller than 0.1 eV. There must have been some updates on this…